Error in start_top:end_top : NA/NaN argument after checking that there are no NAs and no NaNs
for (i in 1:5) {
  trends <- gtrends(keyword = name_gruppen_cleaned[[i]],
                time = zeit_gruppen[[i]],
                geo = "US",
                gprop = "web",
                hl = "en-US",
                category = 0,
                compared_breakdown = FALSE,
                low_search_volume = FALSE,
                cookie_url = "http://trends.google.com/Cookies/NID",
                tz = 0,
                onlyInterest = FALSE)

  print(trends) 
}

When I run this code R returns this "Error in start_top:end_top : NA/NaN argument". I have checked with anyNA(unlist(name_gruppen_cleaned)) and any(is.nan(unlist(name_gruppen_cleaned))) if there are any NAs or NaNs in name_gruppen_cleaned, but there are not.
Does anyone know what I can do?

OP, always include the necessary pkgs for your code: library(gtrendsR).
